# Code::Blocks (MinGW) compilation error on #include <priority_queue>

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks 17.12 with the default MinGW GCC C++ compiler (with -std=c++11) on Windows 10. I have built several C++ console projects without issues. However, when I include the STL priority_queue class, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: priority_queue: No such file or directory
#include <priority_queue>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

These are my #include directives:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <priority_queue>
#include <iostream>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The header is `#include <queue>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

> Defined in header <queue>